# Google App Engine Client ID is not whitelisted

Tags: android, api, google-app-engine

I've just released my first android application to the Play Store.
This application uses Google App Engine, so I've signed a new ClientId in the API console and written this ClientId inside the backend code, but when I run the released app it still won't recieve any response from the server.

I checked the App Engine log and the error was:
"com.google.api.server.spi.WebApisUserService isClientIdAllowed: Client ID [my client id] is not whitelisted."

Have I missed anything?

Comment: are you using google cloud endpoints?

Comment: yes. (seriously? I have to write 15 characters?....)

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem.  What you need to do is go into your endpoints client and add your client id to the @Api annotation at the top of your endpoint class.  There needs to be an attribute named "clientIds" with the [my client id] as the value.  Redeploy and test again.